Intel IPP has the function ippsConvert_32f24s_Sfs. What could be the order of reverse operation to reproduce 32-bit data out of converted 24bit
I am using the intel IPP function, ippsConvert_32f24s_Sfs (), which converts the 32-bit float data to 24-bit signed char (3 signed character bytes) after scaling the actual data with an arbitrary/programmer-choice scaling factor.
At the receiver end, I wanted to revert the 24 bit data to 32 bit float information with less loss in information. Even though IPP package provides another built-in function (ippsConvert_24s32f) to achieve this requirement, I can not use it since I receive the data in totally different environment.
In this scenario, I would like to know that how the function: ippsConvert_24s32f works to convert 24 bit signed char data to 32 bit float data.
The basic expectation is understanding the operations hid in ippsConvert_24s32f.
Since my float data contains signed values, any missing/mishandling of data may end up with spurious errors.

It looks like the section on "Integer Scaling" (pp. 23-24) of the document https://cdrdv2-public.intel.com/671553/ipps-pdf-12-3-2020.pdf explains this.  It looks like you can specify one of three rounding modes, which should help in your goal to minimize information loss.

The simplistic answer (you may have figured this much out already) is that ippsConvert_24s32f essentially multiplies by pow(2, scalingfactor).  The documentation doesn't make explicitly clear what happens to signed quantities.  But the 24s in the name seems to indicate that it is in fact a signed quantity.

24-bit signed quantities are unusual.  If you're trying to write your own code to take those 3-byte fields on the receiving end and turn them back into 4-byte floats, you will have to be sure to sign extend them, specifically by prepending a fourth high-order byte of either 0x00 or 0xff, based on the high bit of the third byte, in order to obtain a more conventional 4-byte integer which you can then multiply by 2^sf.

@SteveSummit As per the document, the value is scaled by 2^SF (Scale Factor) and the LSB byte is truncated once when ippsConvert_32f24s_Sfs is used. At the receiver end, the challenging part is recreation of lost LSB with less information loss.
If we attempt to pad either 0 or 1 at MSB, we may loose polarity/sign. Hence, padding may work at LSB only.

I don't understand your comment, sorry.  Nothing is "truncated" at the sending end — it is either rounded (if the scaled value will fit in 24 bits) or "saturated".  At the receiving end, there is nothing to "recover".  You have 3 bytes representing a 24-bit signed integer, which will range from -8388608 to +8388607.  If you sign-extend it to 4 bytes and convert it to a 32-bit signed integer, I believe you will able to multiply it by 2^SF to recover your original number.
